# Sharepoint 2013 Online - Newsfeed error

Tags: sharepoint-2013, feed

Adding a news feed from Mysite of Sharepoint 2013 Online  gives this error
"
The following error is returned: The request is invalid. Internal type name: Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException. Internal error code: 14. Contact your system administrator for assistance in solving this problem.
This can not be sent, because there are some problems have occurred."

Adding a newsfeed from home page works though.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i had jquery library refrence in the page. I created a new jquery object using noConflict() and used that instead of the default $. For some reasoms $ caused some issues and i was unable to post in the news feed.

```js
var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
jQ(document).ready(function(){
  //demo code
});
```

Below is the error message that used to get.

```html
The request is invalid. Internal type name : Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException . Internal error code : 14+sharepoint
```

Another reason was i have multiple references of jquery library in my page which was the reason.

Hope this might be useful to someone.

Answer (score -1):

Internal error code 14 says "Invalid_Content_Null_Or_Empty". So it might be possible that the content you are updating is invalid. So you need to check that.